# WAAD Tools for ASP.NET - Exception

Tags: azure

After installing Windows Azure Active Directory Tools for ASP.NET, I receive an exception after opening a web project in VS2012'; and, the Enable Windows Azure Authentication option does not appear in my Project menu so I am unable to use the feature. Uninstalling / reinstalling / rebooting has not helped. This is on Windows 8. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

David, what tools do you mean? The "Identity And Access Tools" or something else? Because the latest and recommended version of the tooling for WAAD (targeting VS2012) is the [Identity and Access Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e) And there is no more "Enable Azure authentication", there is menu item "Identity and Access" where you can configure either ACS or WAAD. And these tooling only work for `.NET 4.5` projects. Hope this helps.

The exception for web project comes from another source. What worked for me (for the web projects) was:

- Manually remove the NuGet Package Manager from Visual Studio.
- Close All instance of Visual Studio
- Manually install the latest version of NuGet Package manager
- now Web Project shall be fine

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I was referring to this: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/02/18/microsoft-asp-net-tools-for-windows-azure-active-directory-visual-studio-2012-4/ At any rate, I disabled the majority of my extensions in VS2012 and re-installed and the exception went away, so I guess some other extension was causing the trouble.

Comment: Use [this one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e) as it is the most recent version. And certainly works pretty well with the GA of WAAD. Plus, it is also the required tool when completing the [Scenarios and Solutions walk-trhoughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151121.aspx). Just remove the tool you refer to. It is old and noone refers to it today.